# Tag cloud with bold/light tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-cloud

I am trying to implement a tag cloud like `Amazon.co.uk` [see here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/tagging/cloud/ref=tag_dpp_pt_icld). my currenct javascript is like this

> ```
> var tags = jq.getJSON(baseUrl + '/ajax/populartags', null, function(json){
>     //create list for tag links
>     jq("<p>").attr("id", "popularTagsList").appendTo("#tagCloud");
>     //create tags
>     jq.each(json, function(i, val) {
>         //create link
>         a = jq("<a>").text(val.Tag).attr({title:"See all pages tagged with " + val.Tag, href:baseUrl + '/item/tag/' + val.Tag});
>         a.css("fontSize", (val.Count / 10 < 1) ? val.Count / 10 + 1 + "em": (val.Count / 10 > 4) ? "4em" : val.Count / 10 + "em");
>
>         //add to list
>         a.appendTo("#popularTagsList");
>     });
> });
> ```

is it possible to add ligten/darken functionality to this code?

Comment: Assuming your background is white, you can make it dark by default and add opacity style based on the same algorithm as size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the approach to take would be to adjust the color. In order to "lighten" the color, increase the value for each of RGB components of that color. To "darken" it, decrease the values. If that doesn't make sense or if you'd like a detailed code sample, post a comment and I'll get back with an update shortly.

Comment: Hi Rick, I am really not that experiences when it comes to css/colors etc. If you don't mind, can you provide a code sample?